# web2py development editor with auto completion, indentation, easy navigation, try view for HTML layout

Tags: python, web-development, editor, code-beautification

Which editor can be used with auto completion feature, indentation and easy navigation for web2py .

And also with Default features web2py feature like try view for the html layout.

Comment: What have you tried? Googling `web2py  IDE` gives a bunch of possibilities. Are those the ***only*** features that you require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/web2py.html

PyCharm supports Web2Py development.

Web2Py support in PyCharm includes:

Dedicated project type .

Possibility to open an existing Web2Py project. So doing, PyCharm will recognize project structure, choose the proper template language, and create run/debug configurations.

When a new Web2Py project is created, PyCharm creates a dedicated run/debug configuration for launching a web2Py server.

Web2Py template language.

Navigation between views and templates using the gutter icons.

Code completion and resolve.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/web2py.html

PyCharm supports Web2Py development.

Web2Py support in PyCharm includes:

```
Dedicated project type .

Possibility to open an existing Web2Py project. So doing, PyCharm will recognize project structure, choose the proper template language, and create run/debug configurations.

When a new Web2Py project is created, PyCharm creates a dedicated run/debug configuration for launching a web2Py server.

Web2Py template language.

Navigation between views and templates using the gutter icons.

Code completion and resolve.
```